# Strange Behaviour of a @Html.ActionLink

Tags: razor

I am crafting a menu with `Bootstrap` in a `razor` Layout, but I am in a trouble with a simple `@Html.ActionLink`,

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Editorial</li>
    <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Posts/">Posts</a></li>
    @*<li>@Html.ActionLink("Posts", "Index", "Posts",htmlAttributes: new { role = "menuitem", tabIndex = "-1" })</li>*@
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tags", "Index", "Tags", htmlAttributes: new { role = "menuitem", tabIndex = "-1" })</li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdowns</li>
    <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Aligninment options</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Headers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Disabled menu items</a></li>
</ul>
```

The following statement doesn't work like I want

```
@Html.ActionLink("Tags", "Index", "Tags", htmlAttributes: new { role = "menuitem", tabIndex = "-1" })
```

This is the rendering which I have:

```
<li class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Editorial</li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/Posts/">Posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/?Length=4" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Tags</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdowns</li>
        <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aligninment options</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Headers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Disabled menu items</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Why **@Html.ActionLink("Tags", "Index", "Tags", htmlAttributes: new { role = "menuitem", tabIndex = "-1" })** are rendered in `<a href="/?Length=4" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Tags</a>` ?

Comment: You are using wrong method overload or passing wrong parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may solve the issue.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Tags", "Index", "Tags", null, htmlAttributes: new { role = "menuitem", tabIndex = "-1" })
```